# I want to show simple toast message. is it possible?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i have a button

```
   <button type='button" ng-click="toast()">
```

i simply want to add a functionality to shoe toast message as hello world, while clicking the button.

give me each steps  to do it?

is it possible?

Comment: may be you can use directive and on click of that button make directive visible using scope variable

Comment: Can you update you controller code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is of course possible.

```
 <button type='button" ng-click="toast()">
```

**JS** Using ionic functions

```
    $scope.toast = function(){
      $ionicLoading.show({
            template: 'Hello World'
        });
      $timeout(function() {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        }, 1000);
    }
```

and don't forget to inject

```
$ionicLoading
```

and

```
$timeout
```

Or you can use plugin also for toast
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/toast/

Answer (score 0):

it's one line code for show like a toast

```
                $ionicLoading.show({
                    template: 'Connection Failed',
                    noBackdrop: true,
                    duration: 1000
                });
```

otherwise used [ngCordova Toast](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/toast/) plugin.

thanks.